# Can't select value of GetElementByName with custom jQuery form dropdown validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate, getelementsbyname

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) and trying to validate two time fields. I want to make sure that if "All" is selected for one field that it is true for the other and and `end time` is larger than `start time`

Here is the HTML:

```
 <form id="schedule">
 <select name='start_hour' id='start_hour'>
    <option value='All00'>All</option>
    <option value='0000'>00</option>
    <option value='0100'>01</option>
    <option value='0200'>02</option>
    <option value='0300'>03</option>...
</select>
 and 
<select name='end_hour' id='end_hour'>
    <option value='All00'>All</option>
    <option value='0000'>00</option>
    <option value='0100'>01</option>
    <option value='0200'>02</option>
    <option value='0300'>03</option>...
</select>
 </form>
```

Here is the custom rule:

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod(  "schedule", function(value, element) { 

    var start_hour = document.getElementsByName("start_hour");
    var end_hour = document.getElementsByName("end_hour");

    alert(start_hour.value);
    alert(end_hour.value);
    if (start_hour.value == "All00" && end_hour.value !="All00") 
    { 
        alert('end hour all error')
        return false;
          }
        else if (end_hour.value == "All00" && start_hour.value !="All00") 
    { 
        alert('start hour all error')
        return false;
          }
          else if (end_hour.value <= start_hour.value ){
              alert('end hour must be larger error')
        return false;
          }

    else return true; 
  },  "Error with schedule");
```

for some reason `alert(start_hour.value);` returns "undefined" I also tried to use `getElementbyID` and that failed too. I'm really new to Javascript so I know it's probally something simple.

**[JsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/jm6qR/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use getElementsByName with jQuery
Try this instead, [jQuery Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('select[name="start_hour"]')
```

or since you seem to have the id the same as the name you can use this selector instead

```
$('select#start_hour')
```

Your Validator Method should be constructed like this

```
 jQuery.validator.addMethod(  "schedule", function(value, element) { 
    var start_hour = $('select#start_hour');
    var end_hour = $('select#end_hour');

    alert(start_hour.val());
    alert(end_hour.val());

    if (start_hour.val() == "All00" && end_hour.val() !="All00") { 
        alert('end hour all error')
        return false;
    }
    else if (end_hour.val() == "All00" && start_hour.val() !="All00") { 
        alert('start hour all error')
        return false;
    }
    else if (end_hour.val() <= start_hour.val() ) {
        alert('end hour must be larger error')
        return false;
    }
    else return true; 
  },  "Error with schedule");
```

Comment: nope, `var start_hour = $('input[name="start_hour"]'); alert(start_hour.value)` still seems to return `undefined` See http://jsfiddle.net/BandonRandon/4PrM7/

Comment: If using a jQuery selector you'll need to use .val() instead of .value, but yeah, might as well use jQuery if you're already using it.

Comment: Well @BrandonRandon when using jQuery you must realize you are returning jQuery objects with the selector and not DOM object.  give me a sec and I will modify your code to fully use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByName returns an array, even if there's only one result, so you need to specify that you want the first one.

```
var start_hour = document.getElementsByName("start_hour")[0];
var end_hour = document.getElementsByName("end_hour")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery's ID selector '#'

The following also works:

```
var start_hour = $("#start_hour");
var end_hour = $("#end_hour");

alert(start_hour.val());
alert(end_hour.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName (note the "s") returns an array so you would have to reference the start value via: `start_hour[0].value`. Bu i agree with John you should definatly use the jquery selector.